# Raffle Probably

Tags: probability, statistics

I need some help calculating the chance of winning a raffle from some smarter people.

There are $600$ tickets with $11$ drawings. I need to calculate the odds of winning the $11$th drawing (grand prize). I have $5$ tickets. Winning numbers are put back into the pot.

Comment: If there is no rule against winning multiple prizes, then unless I have misunderstood the problem, your question is equivalent to asking : what are the chances of winning the very first prize?

Comment: Thank you, there is only one prize and they are only choosing the 11th drawing. Do the odds change vs only 1 drawing? I don’t know. In my mind I can only see them as being worse. It’s like having to win twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Do the odds change vs only 1 drawing? I don’t know. In my mind I can only see them as being worse. It’s like having to win twice.

Very critical point.  Righter's answer, which I agree with, gives the mathematical justification for the conclusion that the odds don't change.  However, personally, I regard Probability/Combinatorics as different from other Math topics in that (in my opinion) intuition plays a larger role here.  Therefore, I will try to give an entirely intuitive argument of why Righter's answer is accurate.

To understand this, you have to first understand the idea of *independent events*.  The classic example is flipping a coin.  If you flip a coin $11$ times, the chance of (for example) getting a heads on the $11$-th toss is exactly the same as your chances of getting a heads on the $4$-th toss, or the $7$-th toss.  Each event (heads on the $11$-th toss, heads on the $4$-th toss, heads on the $7$-th toss) has a probability of $(1/2)$ of occurring.

In the present problem, the exact same procedure was followed for each drawing.  In particular, a person is allowed to have their name drawn multiple times.  Therefore, the chances that a person's name (for example) occurred on the $11$-th drawing is the same as the chances that the person's name occurred on the $4$-th drawing or the $7$-th drawing.  Each drawing was an *independent event* that was in no way affected by the results of any of the other drawings.

Therefore, intuitively, the chance that a person's name occurred on the $11$-th drawing is the same as the chances that the person's name occurred on the $1$-st drawing.

---

In the above argument, I used the idea of independent events.  This was justified by the presumption that a person's name might occur in multiple drawings.  In fact, although it may be more difficult to intuitively grasp, the constraint that a person's name might occur in multiple drawings is not critical to the final answer.

Suppose that the name that occurs in each drawing is discarded, rather than put *back in the bin*.  Then, no person's name can occur on more than one drawing.  In this situation, the 11 events that pertain to a name occuring on drawing # $n$, where $n$ is in $\{1,2,3, \cdots, 11\}$, are **dependent** rather than independent events.  For example, if a person's name occurs on drawing #1, then that person's name can't occur on any subsequent drawing.

This begs the question: under the revised constraint, where the drawings are dependent rather than independent events, why are the chances of a person's name occurring on the $11$-th drawing **still** the same as the chances of the person's name occurring on the $1$-st drawing?

To intuitively understand why, assume that there are exactly $100$ people whose names are *in the bin*, and that the names will be drawn from the bin (*without replacement*).  This means that no person's name can occur on more than 1 drawing.  (At random) exactly $1$ of those names will represent the winner of the $1$-st drawing and (at random) exactly $1$ of those names will represent the winner of the $11$-th drawing.

Therefore, the chances of a person's name occurring on the $1$-st drawing are $(1/100)$ and the chances of a person's name occurring on the $11$-th drawing are also $(1/100)$.  So, as with the independent events, **but for a different reason**, the chances of a person's name occurring on the $11$-th drawing are still the same as the chances of that person's name occurring on the $1$-st drawing.

Comment: Thank you very much for this!

Answer (score 0):

The key point here is that *winning numbers are put back into the pot.* We don't care who won the first $10$ draws.

This means that the probability of winning the first time is the same as the probability of winning the eleventh time because the sample space is exactly the same.

So the probability of winning the eleventh time is $\frac{5}{600}=\frac 1 {120}$